# where do i put the code to read possible multiple inbound mail attachments and is it correct?

Tags: apex-email-service

I have begged, borrowed and modified code to read incoming email with an APEX Class.  It seems to work. The last function I need is to read multiple attachments and write them to a file.

**My current code is:**

```
global class Email_PO_Box_Class implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){

        // Create an inboundEmailResult object for returning 
        // the result of the Force.com Email Service
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

        String myPlainText = '';

        // Add the email plain text into the local variable

        try
        {
            myPlainText = email.plainTextBody.substring(0, email.plainTextBody.indexOf('<stop>'));
        }
        catch (System.StringException e)
        {
            myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;
            System.debug('No <stop> in email: ' + e);
        }

        // new Mail record to be created

        Email_PO__c[] newMail = new Email_PO__c[0];

        // There should be no duplicates as email was written only once
        // If there is more than 1 contact with the same email address
        // an exception will be thrown and the catch statement will be called



        try {Integer counter = [ Select count() 
                                FROM E_mail__c 
                                Where E_mail_Address__c = :email.fromAddress ]; 

             //yes or no does email exist begin                                                     

             // change the ccaddresses array into a string
             String listCCAddress = '';
             if (email.ccAddresses != null) {
                 for(String strCC: email.ccAddresses)   {
                     listCCAddress += strCC+','; 
                 } }

             // change the toaddresses array into a string
             String listToAddress = '';
             if (email.toAddresses != null) {
                 for(String strTO: email.toAddresses)   {
                     listToAddress += strTO+','; 
                 }}

             if (counter == 1)  {    
                 // email already exists
                 newMail.add(new Email_PO__c(myPlainText__c = myPlainText,                                         
                                             Priority__c = 'Normal',
                                             Status__c = 'Inbound Email',
                                             email_subject__c = email.subject,
                                             email_fromAddress__c = email.fromAddress,
                                             email_replyTo__c = email.replyTo,
                                             email_fromName__c = email.fromName,
                                             email_htmlBody__c = email.htmlBody,
                                             email_toAddresses__c = listToAddress,
                                             email_ccaddresses__c = listCCAddress,  
                                             env_toAddress__c = env.toAddress,
                                             Exists__c = 'yes'
                                            ));
             } else {
                 // email needs to be added
                 newMail.add(new Email_PO__c(myPlainText__c = myPlainText,
                                             Priority__c = 'Normal',
                                             Status__c = 'Inbound Email',
                                             email_subject__c = email.subject,
                                             email_fromAddress__c = email.fromAddress,
                                             email_replyTo__c = email.replyTo,
                                             email_fromName__c = email.fromName,
                                             email_htmlBody__c = email.htmlBody,
                                             email_toAddresses__c = listToAddress,  
                                             email_ccaddresses__c = listCCAddress,  
                                             env_toAddress__c = env.toAddress,
                                             Exists__c = 'No'
                                            ));

             }
             //yes or no does email exist end


             // Insert the new Task and it will be created and appended to the contact record
             insert newMail;




            }

        // If there is an exception with the query looking up
        // the contact this QueryException will be called.
        // and the exception will be written to the Apex Debug logs

        catch (System.QueryException e) {
            System.debug('Query Issue: ' + e);
        }

        // Set the result to true, no need to send an email back to the user
        // with an error message

        result.success = true;

        // Return the result for the Force.com Email Service
        return result;
    }

}
```

**The code I think I want to add is:**

```
// Save attachments, if any                                                             
 if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
          for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                  Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                  // attach to the newly created contact record
                  attachment.ParentId = newMail.Id;
                  attachment.Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename;
                  attachment.Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body;
                  }
     insert attachment;
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                         

 if (email.TextAttachment != null && email.TextAttachment.size() > 0) {
          for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.TextAttachment.size() ; i++) {
                  Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                  // attach to the newly created contact record
                  attachment.ParentId = newMail.Id;
                  attachment.Name = email.TextAttachment[i].filename;
                  attachment.Body = email.TextAttachment[i].body;
                  }
     insert attachment;
          }
```

Comment: Bill -- take those inserts out of for loops -- they should be placed into a List and inserted in bulk with one operation

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed that error but now created the error:
"Variable does not exist: attachment"  I thought it was defined, but I guess not.  Also doe it matter where I put this code?

Comment: edit your post with the revised code

Comment: Bill, I have edited your post to make your code readable. You can edit your own posts at any time by clicking on edit at the bottom left of your post. To easily format your code, simply select your code and click on the pre-formatted text icon. Alternatively, you can add 4 spaces to each line to get it to display as pre-formatted text. Visit the [Help] if you need more assistance with the editor.